# Determine if there's a justified reason to block/cancel an HTTPS request (but not HTTP)

Tags: tls, http

I've recently found out that a microservice I've been using (`worldtimeapi.org`)
isn't accessible via `https` (but is via `http`) on networks other than my home network (I've tried a university's public network, which has no password, and using my mobile network, both on the phone and via a hotspot).

On firefox on my laptop, I get `PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR` when using my mobile phone's network.

However the security certificate seems to be valid- my browser doesn't complain when entering the site on my home network via `HTTPS`, and random websites I found by googling "website security verification" say it's secure.

Which leaves me wondering - is my ability to access the site on my laptop an indication of a security problem in my own network, or... what?

**How can I find out more about why a certain website might be blocked?**

**Edit:**
While Jonathan gave good suggestions on what to look at (and I followed some). *In this specific case*, I managed to resolve the issue by adding `www.` after the `https://`. the same networks which wouldn't let me browse to the website via `https` allow it when I add `www.`. I've gone back and forth to make sure it's not a coincidence, and it seems not to be.

Comment: The server in question is strange - sometimes it works and sometimes not. Same IP, same client program, practically same time.  Maybe there is just some broken load balancer or similar in front or the site is overloaded. But in general: there is no simple way to find out why one got blocked unless  one get a clear error message. Deliberate blocking and malfunctioning often look the same, like in this case.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich odd, was whatever error you got when the site fails to load/connect equally devoid of useful information (just something about the connection being reset)? To me it either consistently works or consistently does not work, depending on which network I use.

Comment: "Connection reset" is nothing to do with the certificate on your computer. It is a connection problem. It's possible that your ISP blocks this site. But it's more likely that the site is just broken (temporarily or permanently)

Comment: Connection reset is a common problem if a load balancer cannot reach its backend or if the site is overloaded. In this case the initial TCP connection succeeded but was then immediately closed on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is troubleshooting to isolate the error by testing each intermediate component.

Generally it looks like this:

Browser -> (local name resolution) -> internet -> dns
Browser -> internet -> server
Browser -> root-certs

First you need to make sure you’re always resolving the same up address.

Make sure all the devices you use have the same root certificate for verification.

Find out if you have a man in the middle intercepting your traffic. Difficult to do and that’s why they have tls and why sites should set [hsts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security). Mitm is common and often leverages a downplay attack. That is convincing your client that the server doesn’t support higher encryption so the client falls back to insecure protocols like http.

Use a vpn like expressvpn or a digital ocean instance with openvpn installed.

Try different devices over the same network to determine if the fault is with your device or the network.

If the fault persists across networks, then it’s the server.